# In MySQL stored procedure getting output 1 in count and if I am executing only query then I am getting output 0

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
SELECT COUNT(id) INTO student_count FROM student_info WHERE roll_no=roll_no and division_id = division_id and institute_id=institute_id and academic_year_id = academic_year;
```

I am getting **student_count = 1**
 when I am trying to execute stored procedure.

When I am executing direct query as below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM student_info WHERE division_id=9 AND institute_id=1 and academic_year_id =11 and roll_no='12617690';
```

I am getting result 0 which is right. My procedure is:

```
**CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE smart_school.create_student(IN academic_year int(11),IN standard_id int(11),IN division_id int(11),IN student_user_id int(11),IN gr_no VARCHAR(20),IN roll_no VARCHAR(50),IN institute_id INT(11),IN maker_id INT(11),OUT create_student_result varchar(20))
BEGIN
 DECLARE student_id int;
 DECLARE student_count int;
 DECLARE semester varchar(10);  

 DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
 BEGIN
   SET create_student_result = "failure";
   SELECT @create_student_result;
 ROLLBACK;
 END;

 IF NOT EXISTS (select id from role_user where user_id = student_user_id and role_id = 3 and institute_id=institute_id limit 0,1) THEN
  BEGIN  
    select COUNT(id) INTO student_count  from student_info WHERE roll_no=roll_no and division_id = division_id and institute_id=institute_id and academic_year_id = academic_year;
    if student_count < 1 then
        BEGIN
            START TRANSACTION;
            insert into student (is_active,user_id,maker_id,caste_id,category_id,created_at,updated_at) values ('1',student_user_id,maker_id,1,1,NOW(),NOW());
            SET student_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
            select semester_id into semester from division where institute_id=institute_id and standard_id=standard_id limit 0,1;
            insert into student_info (roll_no,is_active,institute_id,student_id,standard_id,semester_id,division_id,academic_year_id,maker_id,created_at,updated_at) values (roll_no,'1',institute_id,student_id,standard_id,semester,division_id,academic_year,maker_id,now(),now());
            insert into institute_student (is_active,gr_no,institute_id,student_id,admission_standard_id,admission_year_id,created_at,updated_at) values ('1',gr_no,institute_id,student_id,standard_id,academic_year,now(),now());
            insert into role_user (user_id,role_id,institute_id,is_active,joining_date,created_at) values (student_user_id,3,institute_id,'1',now(),now());             
            COMMIT; 
            SET create_student_result = "success"; 
            SELECT @create_student_result;
        END;
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SET create_student_result = "duplicate_rollno";
            SELECT @create_student_result;
        END;
    END IF;
  END; 
ELSE 
    BEGIN
       SET create_student_result = "already_exists";
       SELECT @create_student_result;
    END;
END IF;

END**
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054298/in-mysql-stored-procedure-getting-output-1-in-count-and-if-i-am-executing-only-q?sfb=2)

Comment: Those are two different queries, in which query 1 pretty much is allowed to query your complete table, and query 2 is limited to a single subset, so yes, it will most likely give different results. Can you update your question and example so it becomes something answerable?